# move product overview below product review in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, addtocart, page-layouts

help me to move the product overview below product review in product details page like this...and help me to make qty and add to cart button in a single line...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create new XML in your theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

**Add below code in XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I need short description should come below review like provided image

Comment: In default magento you can see same http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/stellar-solar-jacket.html please clear your question on which position you need to review